# Правильно ли в книге написаны примеры

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Начал заниматься по книге C# для школьников и столкнулся сразу же с трудностью. А именно в примерах, которые приводят в книге не понятно почему подчёркивается всё красной линией и не работает.

Допустим этот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
class Animal
{
    public string kindOfAnimal;
    public string name;
    public int numberOfLegs;
    public int height;
    public int length;
    public string color;
    bool hasTail;
    protected bool isMammal;
    private bool spellingCorrect;
}

class Zoo
{
    public void GetAnimal()
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        a.kindOfAnimal = "Kangaroo";
        a.isMammal = false;
        a.spellingCorrect = true;
    }
}
```

А вот так правильно? Насколько я понял, мне сейчас подчёркивает две строки:

```
a.isMammal = false;
a.spellingCorrect = true;
```

Так как они protected и private? Так?

А вот скриншот из книги. Она называется C# для школьников.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете поделиться цитатой или ссылкой на книгу, где такое написано?

Comment: В школах шарп преподают ? Это в каком классе?

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, это книга с майкросовтовского сайта, легко гуглится по названию. Нужный код на странице 31. https://download.microsoft.com/documents/rus/msdn/c_sharp2.pdf

Comment: @Qwertiy это не книга, а зло какое-то. Надо создать тему с очень плохими примерами и книгами, чтобы никто больше не велся на такую ерунду

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, там ещё и поля свойствами называют - попалось, пока скроллил к примеру...

Comment: @Qwertiy первый же пример (7 стр). Без установленной локализации - пытаются вывести русский текст в консоль. И нигде не указано, что могут получится краказябры в большинстве случаев)

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, C# замечательно работает с кодировками и выводит на консоль юникод. Вот уж тут вероятность каких-то проблем почти нулевая. Это ж не плюсы. И я очень удивлён, что в джаве с кодировками тоже фигня...

Comment: @Qwertiy да, тут простите, сам виноват. только у меня наверное такие проблемы, при переустановке винды - всегда надо ручками дать ей локализацию через реестр, а то краказябры везде. (Почему у меня всегда по стандарту стоит какая-то другая кодировка и локализация, что отличается от нормальной:(  ) странно, что об этой книге пишут https://megamozg.ru/post/6744/

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, но ведь у шарпа юникод. Я же выводил символы вне текущей кодировки и проблем не возникало.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38731/discussion-between-yurii-manziuk-and-qwertiy).

Comment: Ответьте мне пожалуйста в чате.

Answer (score 7):

Да, пример в книге неправильный. Это и не должно работать.

---

Смотрите.

Что такое класс, по сути? Это описание объекта, которое содержит *данные* и *действия* (которые называют обычно *код*).

Код в классе лежит не весь одной кучей, а кусками (они называются *функции* или *методы*). В вашем примере код лежит просто в классе:

```
class Zoo
{
    Animal a = new Animal();
    a.kindOfAnimal = "Kangaroo";
    a.isMammal = false;
    a.spellingCorrect = true;
}
```

Но его нужно уложить в функцию, чтобы потом можно было этот кусок кода вызвать:

```
class Zoo
{
    public Animal CreateAnimal()
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        a.kindOfAnimal = "Kangaroo";
        a.isMammal = false;
        a.spellingCorrect = true;
        return a;
    }
}
```

В этом случае можно будет заставить этот кусок кода выполниться:

```
Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
Animal kangaroo = zoo.CreateAnimal();
```

---

Обновление:

Да, присвоение полям `isMammal` и `spellingCorrect` тоже не должно работать. Обращаться «снаружи» можно лишь к публичным (то есть, открытым) данным.

Comment: public Animal CreateAnimal() - а это что? Тоже класс, который мы создаём?

Comment: А. Это метод, который мы создали в классе Zoo?

Comment: @Piston: Ага, это вместо кода прямо в классе я положил код в метод.

Comment: Но Animal a = new Animal(); может ведь лежать в классе Zoo. Просто члены класса Animal недоступны вне методов, конструкторов класса Zoo.

Comment: Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
Animal kangaroo = zoo.CreateAnimal();
А это что?

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade *"Просто члены класса Animal недоступны вне методов, конструкторов класса Zoo."* нет, это не так. Дело не в недоступности методов, а в недоступности операторов.

Comment: @Piston: `Zoo zoo` — объявление _переменной_ `zoo` типа `Zoo`. `= new Zoo()` — создали новый объект типа `Zoo` или положили в переменную. `Animal kangaroo` — объявили переменную типа `Animal`. `= zoo.CreateAnimal()` — запустили метод `CreateAnimal` объекта, лежащего в `zoo`, и положили в переменную (ссылку на) объект `Animal`, который создал этот метод в результате своей работы.

Answer (score 4):

Для примера возьмем 2 класса: **Animal** и **Elephant**

```
class Animal{}

class Elephant{}
```

Экземпляр класса `Animal` можно создать и поместить в поле класса `Elephant`,
но просто выполнять операторы непосредственно внутри класса (т. е. вне методов, конструкторов, свойств и т. д.) - нельзя.

```
class Animal
{
   public string Name;
}

class Elephant
{
   Animal elephant = new Animal();
   elephant.Name = "Слон Микки"; //Нельзя
}
```

К членам класса `Animal` (методы, поля и т.д) вы можете обращаться через конструкторы, методы, события и т.д.

Например:

```
class Animal
{
    public string Name;
}

class Elephant
{
    Animal animal = new Animal();

    public void GetName()
    {
        animal.Name = "Слон";
    }
}
```

Описал как можно кратко. Книгу, которую читаете Вы - сожгите :)

Советую для чтения книги, которые описаны: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/180583)

Удачного кодинга...

Comment: Тут дело не столько в том, что нельзя к ним "обратиться в классе", сколько в том, что внутри класса не может находиться операторов, только объявления. Первая строчка не подчеркивается потому что это корректное объявление приватного поля с инициализацией - но остальные строчки корректными объявлениями не являются.

Comment: Очень сложно расписать свою мысль, но чуток поправил.

Comment: _"но обращаться к членам Animal внутри самого класса Elephant - нельзя" - о_О

Comment: Вы написали цитату. Что в ней не так?

Comment: Все так, просто я чуток не правильно выразился. Члены класса недоступны вне методов, констукторов и т.д.

Comment: @Piston, кажется, исправил...

Comment: Qwertiy спасибо) Я уже править начал) Нажал на ок, ошибка) У меня было бы так: Экземпляр класса **Animal** можно создать в самом классе **Elephant**,
но обращаться к членам **Animal** внутри самого класса **Elephant** без использования методов, конструкторов - нельзя.

Comment: `Animal animal = new Animal() { Name = "Слон" };` - упс.. всё-таки можно :)

Comment: Это уже синтаксический сахар) И насколько далеко можно пойти таким описанием класса?)

Comment: Насколько хватит извращённости программиста: http://ideone.com/aFNiME

Comment: А извращенности программистов нет предела) Док-во тому - комменты и ответы на любые вопросы)

Answer (score 1):

Почему все напали на пример. Он в книге абсолютно верный. Или мы читать разучились? Там же красным по белому написано, что две следующие строки не будут выполнены. Они как раз и говорят, что так писать не получится.

Comment: `a.kindOfAnimal = "Kangaroo";` внутри класса, без метода, не откомпилируется

Comment: Да, согласен - по скриншоту видно, что там действительно всё находится внутри класса, а не внутри метода. Наверное предполагалось, что это будет внутри метода, но его забыли. Тогда да - пример из скриншота неверный, но комментарии в нём всё равно правильные, если исходить из того, что эти все эти строки должны быть в методе класса Zoo.